# Java / JAI - save an image gray-scaled

Tags: java, jai

I try to save the tiff instead of coloure gray-scaled. How could I do this? (JAI must be used, because it is a tiff!)

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to download the [JAI Image I/O Tools](https://jai-imageio.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html#Release_builds), which provides ImageIO adapters for JAI. Once you've installed that, it's smooth sailing.

```
final BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File("frabozzle.tif"));
final BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(
    in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
out.getGraphics().drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
ImageIO.write(out, "TIFF", new File("graybozzle.tif"));
```

Comment: hmm, and how could I save the image without any compression grayscaled?

Comment: I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6422430.
It is in line out.getGraphics().

Comment: in = (java.awt.image.BufferedImage) BufferedImage@381d92; type = 0 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 1 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@1d8e92 transparency = 1 alpha = false isAlphaPre = false sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster@7e5130

Comment: Problem is solved. My image, but IrfanView displays it in red color. I do not know why, but I display it in other programs well, but not in GIMP :-(

Answer (score 3):

Given a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), you can use the [`filter()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) method of [`ColorConvertOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html), as shown in this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/d4c436ab64d4ced4).