# Convert a bitmap image to an uncompressed tif image in Java

Tags: java, image, tiff, jai

I'm trying to convert a bitmap image into an uncompressed tif file for use with the Tesseract OCR engine.

I can use this method to produce a compressed tif file...

```
final BufferedImage bmp = ImageIO.read(new File("input.bmp"));
ImageIO.write(bmp, "jpg", new File("output.tif"));
```

This produces an empty tif file when the "jpg" is changed to tif as these files are dealt with in Java Advanced Imaging (JAI).

How can I create an uncompressed tif image? Should I decompress the tif image produced from the above code or is there another way to handle the conversion process?

Any examples provided would be much appreciated.

Thanks

kingh32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ImageWriteParam` to disable compression:

```
TIFFImageWriterSpi spi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
ImageWriter writer = spi.createWriterInstance();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);

ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("output.tif"));
writer.setOutput(ios);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bmp, null, null), param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time before i was facing the problems with tiff images reading and conversion with jai.
I found that it need to install support for working with tiff images in jai, then it works fine for me u can also get it form here:
 https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jaiio-1.0_01-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

and install over a jvm then it will also work for you.
you can also have a look here
[Java / JAI - save an image gray-scaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209766/java-jai-save-an-image-gray-scaled)