# How to save Bitmap to .tiff in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, tiff

I know it is possible to save bitmap to png or jpg

now i want to save bitmap to .tiff,anybody can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a bitmap image to an uncompressed tif image in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845376/convert-a-bitmap-image-to-an-uncompressed-tif-image-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Android does not have native support for saving TIFF files.

You best bet would be to get the raw byte array, and then using either a Java or NDK library (like [libtiff](http://libtiff.org/)) to save it as a TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is is a repost from here:
[Convert a bitmap image to an uncompressed tif image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845376/convert-a-bitmap-image-to-an-uncompressed-tif-image-in-java)

To answer the question, the above answer suggested the following using the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) library:

```
TIFFImageWriterSpi spi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
ImageWriter writer = spi.createWriterInstance();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);

ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("output.tif"));
writer.setOutput(ios);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bmp, null, null), param);
```

Comment: Did this worked for you @wseme.  Did you add any dependencies while importing in android ? If so can you pleas update what line should i add in android gradle for dependencies?

Comment: implementation 'com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:1.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

You always can save the Bitmap as `.png` and convert it to `.tiff`

Answer (score 0):

Android hasn't support for tiff images. You should use some library for working with tiff. For example my:  https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory